# How to handle "MemoryError" in sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gaussian

I want to fit my data in `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` model, but there is **MemoryError**.

Someone recommended to change `covariance_type('full' -> 'diag')`, but I need full covariance.
Now my memory is 24GB.

I used this code :
`GaussianMixture(n_components=1000, max_iter=100, random_state=random_state)`

And my data is composed of 1,600 columns and 33,000 samples.

Could you recommend how to fit my data in Gaussian Mixture model?
Not Using sklearn but using another package or codes is OK.